# X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set

Tags: ubuntu, x11, nvidia-jetson

I want to enable x11 forwarding on macOS connected to a Jetson Xavier nx. However, upon connecting:

```
sudo ssh -Xvvv id@host
```

The connection establishes successfully. But in the verbose logs, I'm getting the following:

```
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to proto1 ([192.168.1.106]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug1: X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set
debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SUDO_COMMAND
debug3: Ignored env SUDO_USER
debug3: Ignored env SUDO_UID
debug3: Ignored env SUDO_GID
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

```
X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set
```

And in order for X11 forwarding to work, the DISPLAY variable must be set upon connection. Manually setting the DISPLAY like so:

```
export DISPLAY=http://localhost:22
```

doesn't work either. How to enable X11 forwarding?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem trying to get X11 forwarding to XQuartz. I believe when you ssh from Mac, if DISPLAY in the Mac terminal is not set, then the ssh client does not know where to forward the X11 traffic. So I just did:

```
DISPLAY=:0
```

in the Mac terminal, then `ssh -X` and it worked.

Comment: This works. I can be seen by comparing the environment (env command) of an XQuartz terminal and an iterm2 or Mac OS default terminal environment.

Comment: +1, the DISPLAY variable is not set in the Mac terminal by default. After setting it with `export DISPLAY=:0`, it gets forwarded to the remote server with `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` and everything works as expected. Alternatively, one can ssh using the terminal that comes with XQuartz as it has the DISPLAY variable set by default.

Comment: This also works on windows 10 ssh (with an X server like VcXsrv). `set DISPLAY=<ip>:0.0` and then `ssh -Y`

Answer (score 6):

Well there should definitely not be an `http://` in there, and I think your `:22` came from the SSH port and is not an X11 display number you should be using. Your DISPLAY on the local machine is almost always `:0.0`, and if you don't already see that when you `echo $DISPLAY` on your machine, something is probably wrong there.

Make sure you can run X11 applications on your Mac alone first. You may need to install [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/).

Try running without `sudo`; maybe root isn't allowed to talk to your X11 on Mac. Also, maybe try `ssh -X` from within an `xterm` window (which should open up when you open XQuartz manually, or be launchable from its menus) to make sure it picks up the right DISPLAY.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem earlier. It turns out I didn't install X11 forwarding packages on my Mac. So make sure you installed XQuartz by brew:

```
brew install xquartz --cask
```

(Notice that the error message can be like yours when xquartz is not installed on your Mac, so check on your local machine first.)

Then make sure you have `export DISPLAY=:0`, or you can check the `$DISPLAY` by `echo $DISPLAY`. After that, by using verbose `ssh -v -X user@host`, you should find debug message like:

```
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
```

That worked for me. Though the `eog` command shows with slow speed later.